# How can I pass multiple columns from a DataFrame to a scikit-learn FeatureUnion?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

**Solved: see edit below**

I'm experimenting with scikit-learn's `SGDClassifier` to classify a small number of bank transactions. The data is in a Pandas DataFrame – each row is a transaction, with a text description field (which I'm feeding into `TfidfVectorizer`) and a continuous amount field:

```
        Date                       Description   Amount  Balance  Category
0 2011-03-23      CO-OP GROUP 102786 STEVENAGE   -22.55   483.14    Petrol
1 2011-03-23                         O2 UK LTD   -12.77   505.69    Phone
2 2011-03-22                SAINSBURYS COV GDN   -30.84   691.75    Food
```

So far I've been classifying solely on the Description field, but I now want to add in the Amount field. I've been using the `FeatureUnion` example on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) to get started, but I'm struggling to get my data into the expected format.

My code currently looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[self.column]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("union", FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ("description", Pipeline([
                ("selector", ItemSelector(column="Description")),
                ("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer())
            ]))
        ]
    )),
    ("classifier", SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="l2", alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42))
])

print(training_data.head(n=3))
print(training_data.shape)
print(len(training_data["Category"].tolist()))

model = pipeline.fit(training_data, training_data["Category"].tolist())
```

Where `training_data` is the DataFrame. The `df.shape` of training_data is `(538, 5)` and the `len()` of `training_data["Category"].tolist()` is `538`.

When I run this, I'm getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. I assume something is wrong with the format of the data returned by the `ItemSelector.transform` method, but I'm not sure what.

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sci-class.py", line 80, in <module>
    predictions = model.predict(test_data["Description"].tolist())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 326, in predict
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 763, in transform
    for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 758, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 608, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 571, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 109, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 567, in _transform_one
    res = transformer.transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 445, in _transform
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "sci-class.py", line 60, in transform
    return X[self.column]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What's the correct way to pass multiple columns from a DataFrame to a scikit-learn FeatureUnion?

**Edit**

@Vivek Kumar pointed out that the error was thrown by a line I didn't include in the above extract: `predictions = model.predict(test_data["Description"].tolist())`. I was using `tolist()` in the earlier iteration of the code before I added the `FeatureUnion`. So it was all a silly mistake, really.

The below (in combination with the above) is working for me:

```
model = pipeline.fit(training_data, training_data["Category"].tolist())

predictions = model.predict(test_data)
probabilities = model.predict_proba(test_data)
score = model.score(test_data, test_data["Category"].tolist())
labels = sorted(set(training_labels + test_labels))
matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(test_data["Category"].tolist(), predictions, labels=labels)
```

Comment: The problem is in `predictions = model.predict(test_data["Description"].tolist())` and `X[self.column] in Itemselector`. In the first line, you are converting the dataframe column to a list and then you apply itemselector on it to choose that column again.

Comment: You're right! It now works. For some reason I thought the error was thrown during `pipeline.fit`, but as you pointed out, it was actually thrown by `model.predict` which had the out-of-date .tolist() method appended to the training data. I'll update my question with the corrected lines, but this is now working fine.